# Android RecyclerView item text too long

Tags: android, text, scroll, user-experience, truncation

I have a RecyclerView list where some items (text) are too long for the width allowed by the device. I can use android:ellipsize="end" to indicate that the text is truncated but I want to be able to show user the whole text. I can use android:scrollHorizontally="true" and then the text will scroll but there is no visual indication for the user that he needs to scroll it and the text just looks truncated. What would be the good UX for this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1、you can edit your textView like this 
`xml
<TextView
        ...
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="......"/>`

It will auto scrollHorizontal,Or you can use a autoFitTextView in you list item,[auto fit textview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the marquee but it just scrolls back and forth which is not a good user experience for the list item.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:scrollbars="horizontal"` to your recyclerview to show the scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and it doesn't work (no scrollbar shown)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the solution is to wrap the item in HorizontalScrollView and set android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal". This allows for scrolling and there is a horizontal scroll bar for long items.

Answer (score 0):

So, after many investigations, I've found the problem solution:
**This happens due to MARGINS and PADDINGS (and maybe other offset parameters) inside your TextView and its parents.** Just remove them and see the result.

I hope it helped new googlers!

PS:
**If you want to save your offset parameters try to change the layout width parameter inside your TextView and its parents to wrap content (but somewhere also try 0dp or match parent), it also worked for me.** So your UI will look exactly as you want!

Comment: and maxLines and lines property in xml files